# Unable to configure filter, module has no attribute

Tags: python, python-logging

I'm trying to configure a filter for python's logging module.
My directory structure looks like this:

```
- lib
  - logger.py
  - test.py
main.py
```

logger.py:

```
import logging
import logging.config

class Filter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return True

logging.config.dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "filters": {
            "test_filter": {"()": "lib.logger.Filter"},
        },
    }
)
```

test.py:

```
foo = 1
```

main.py:

```
import lib.logger
```

When I run main, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/config.py", line 390, in resolve
    found = getattr(found, frag)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'logger'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/config.py", line 553, in configure
    filters[name] = self.configure_filter(filters[name])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/config.py", line 690, in configure_filter
    result = self.configure_custom(config)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/config.py", line 471, in configure_custom
    c = self.resolve(c)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/config.py", line 393, in resolve
    found = getattr(found, frag)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'logger'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aiman/repos/test/python/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lib.logger
  File "/Users/aiman/repos/test/python/lib/logger.py", line 13, in <module>
    logging.config.dictConfig(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/config.py", line 811, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/config.py", line 555, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure '
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'test_filter'
```

I'm able to import `from lib.test import foo` just fine. So I don't see why it cannot import it?